# Can a string declared outside a lock and used within a lock be changed by another thread?

Tags: c#, multithreading

Is the following code thread-safe? I assume it is because strings are immutable. (Code thrown together for demo purposes)

```
static readonly object _lockObject = new object();

void SomeMethod(string filePath, string fileName)
{
    // Any reason for this to be moved inside the lock?
    string s = Path.Combine(filePath, fileName);

    lock (_lockObject)
    {
       try
       {
          // Other stuff to create the file here. 
       }
       finally
       {
          File.Delete(s);
       }
    }
}
```

I'm curious after reading [this](http://www.albahari.com/threading/part2.aspx#_Locking_and_Atomicity) (first few lines of the section Locking and Atomicity).

Comment: well in your example the string is local so surely nobody can change it from anywhere else than the method itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's thread-safe.

Even removing the lock would make it thread safe :-)

You're only using local variables and static BCL methods (which are always thread-safe).

Comment: removing the lock doesn't sound like an option to me: he might end up with 2 threads working with the same file / fileName (somewhere inside the try) and that won't end well.

Comment: The question was changed after my answer. It was just the File.Delete() call originally

Answer (score 2):

Strings are immutable so they will never change after being constructed.
and since you're local is not passed by ref anywhere the reference won't change either so it safe

Answer (score 1):

It's thread-safe, but any exception thrown by `File.Delete` will replace the real exception when the stack unwinds.